# Is there a way to make a custom ios project template only arc?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am build a custom template that has additional files from another project that was built with ARC. I want to make ARC default to yes and disable it from being toggled off.

I am using this as a reference and have been searching through google for help.
http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to disable it from being turned off ever, but you can set it to default to on in your TemplateInfo.plist for your custom xcode template

```
<key>Project</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SharedSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC</key>
            <string>YES</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

and

```
<key>Targets</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SharedSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC</key>
                <string>YES</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably just have to deal with the 3 *whole seconds* of time being added to your project for each file.

Really, though, it *would* be nice to have more control over Xcode - I hesitate to say me and you are power-users (*we are all **developers**, right*? Developer > Power User). How about we say **power-developers**.

As a power-developer, I would say that something like this would be useful - **but** it *is* just a minor annoyance.

I would say to just deal with it.

To clarify:

## *There is no way to do this.*

Comment: Not really sure this qualifies as an answer.  Feels a lot more like a commentary to me since it doesn't do anything to actually solve the issue.

Comment: @iWasRobbed OK, I'll fix that.

Comment: There, how's that? :)